# How can I highlight some cells in a Tile Map in LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm programming a Strategy RPG using LibGDX, and Tiled as a map editor. I am loading the Tiled map with the Asset Manager and right now I don't have a Texture Atlas (I'm not quite sure yes which will be my definitive textures).

If you are familiar with Strategy RPG games, you should know that when you want to move a character, the cells where you can move it change color. That's what I'm trying to do.

But before figuring that, I'm trying to click a cell and change it's color by changing the texture of the upper layer of that cell, with the following code:

```
TiledMapTileLayer.Cell selectedCell = new TiledMapTileLayer.Cell();
selectedCell.setTile(selectedTileSet.getTile(0));
StaticTiledMapTile selectedTile = new StaticTiledMapTile(selectedSpriteRegion);
selectedCell.setTile(selectedTile);
selectedTileLayer.setCell((int) Math.floor(screenX / 32), (int) Math.floor((viewport.getScreenHeight() - screenY / 32)), selectedCell);
```

That code is inside a `TouchDown` inside a `Screen`, to be called every time I touch a part of the `Screen`.

The layer I use is one I set specifically for the highlighted tiles and it is above the rest of the layers in my code, except for the one that has the characters.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.

Here is the new code:

```
TiledMapTileLayer.Cell selectedCell = new TiledMapTileLayer.Cell();
selectedCell.setTile(selectedTileSet.getTile(1765));
StaticTiledMapTile selectedTile = new StaticTiledMapTile(selectedSpriteRegion);
selectedCell.setTile(selectedTile);
selectedTileLayer.setCell(screenX / 32, (viewport.getScreenHeight() - screenY) / 32, selectedCell);
```

So there were two errors. First that the `id` of the tile was wrong. I thought that because I had one tile, it would be zero, but no, it is 1765 (don't ask me why).

Also, I was setting the wrong cell since the formula I used was wrong. `Math.floor` wasn't necessary and I was dividing before subtracting in the Y position (can't believe I did that).

That's all! Hope this helps to someone with a similar error in the future!